Can we make human skeleton walk? Attaching a natural human gait (model or data) to anatomic skeleton
Anatomically correct human walk is quite useful and interesting to showcase. We seemingly have all we need to do this.
1. Natural gate
Can we attach the walking gait from e.g. Wolfram demonstration Human Walking Animation or similar. Or the actual data like BVH files (thanks to @C.E. for comment about THIS POST). The BVH (Biovision Hierarchical Data) file format is commonly used in motion capture for representing 3D skeletal data and animation. Developed by Biovision, BVH files encode motion data and a hierarchical structure of a skeleton, defining how body parts (bones/joints) are connected and animated over time.

2. Anatomical structure:
To human skeleton (e.g. a previous question that is similar but not really what I am asking):

3. We can move bones partly:
See example in docs: AnatomyPlot3D >> Neat Examples >> 3rd Example:

There is also this post: Biomechanical model of joint movements in human body
THE TASK
Perhaps there are folks here who specialize in anatomy and who already worked with Wolfram anatomy data. It would be interesting to attach a natural human walking gait to anatomic skeleton and make it walk in place computing 1 period of motion. So it can be looped in a video or animation. Any approaches are OK.

Dem bones, dem bones gonna walk around...

This question reminds me of How to build a BVH player.

Edit: Mapping BVH Data.

BVH data points are mapped to graph vertices, which are then manually assigned to corresponding bones.
Using the BVH archive from https://accad.osu.edu/sites/accad.osu.edu/files/Female1_bvh.zip
Preparing BVH data points
Borrowing Sjoerd C. de Vries's parsing code from How to build a bvh player:
filename = "Female1_B01_StandToWalk.bvh"; 
bvh = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> filename, "String"];
bvhHierarchy = 
  StringReplace[
   bvh, ___ ~~ "HIERARCHY" ~~ start__ ~~ "MOTION" ~~ ___ :> start];
bvhMotion = StringReplace[bvh, ___ ~~ "MOTION" ~~ end___ :> end];

tokenize[code_String] := 
 StringSplit[code, (" " | "\n" | "\r" | "\t") ..]
{frames, frameTime, data} = 
  tokenize[
    bvhMotion] /. {___, "Frames:", frs_, "Frame", "Time:", ft_, 
     data__} :> {ToExpression@frs, ToExpression@ft, 
     Partition[N[#, 6] & /@ {data}, Length[{data}]/ToExpression[frs]]};

ClearAll[channelPattern, offsetPattern, bracketPattern]
bracketPattern = PatternSequence["{", Except["{" | "}"] .., "}"];
channelPattern = 
  PatternSequence["CHANNELS", n_, channels__] /; 
   Length[{channels}] == ToExpression[n];
offsetPattern = PatternSequence["OFFSET", x_, y_, z_];

ClearAll[parse]
parse[left___, cp : channelPattern, right___] := 
 expr[parse[left], offset @@ ({cp}[[3 ;; 5]]), 
   channel @@ ({cp}[[6 ;;]]), parse[right]] /; Length[{cp}] == 8
parse[left___, cp : channelPattern, right___] := 
 expr[parse[left], channel @@ ({cp}[[3 ;;]]), parse[right]] /; 
  Length[{cp}] == 5
parse[left___, op : offsetPattern, right___] := 
  expr[parse[left], offset @@ ({op}[[2 ;;]]), parse[right]];
parse[{tokens___}] := parse[tokens];
parse[tokens___] := expr[tokens];

ClearAll[parseBrackets, a]
parseBrackets[left___, h1_, h2_, bp : bracketPattern, right___] := 
  parseBrackets[left, h1 @@ ({bp}[[2 ;; -2]]), right];

makeSlots[tokens_] := 
 Module[{i = 1}, 
  Which[MatchQ[#, 
      Alternatives["Xposition", "Yposition", "Zposition"]], 
     slot[i++], # === "Xrotation", xr[slot[i++]], # === "Yrotation", 
     yr[slot[i++]], # === "Zrotation", zr[slot[i++]], 
     Head[#] == String && StringMatchQ[#, NumberString], 
     ToExpression[#], True, #] & /@ tokens]

xRot[x_] := RotationMatrix[x Degree, {1, 0, 0}];
yRot[y_] := RotationMatrix[y Degree, {0, 1, 0}];
zRot[z_] := RotationMatrix[z Degree, {0, 0, 1}];

channelToRotation[c_channel] := 
 Dot @@ (c /. {xr -> xRot, yr -> yRot, zr -> zRot})
ClearAll[ROOT, JOINT]
ROOT[os_List, d_List, r_List, rest___] := ROOT[os + d, r, rest]
ROOT[os_List, r_List, p : PatternSequence[__JOINT, ___END]] := 
 ROOT[os, r, #] & /@ {p} /; Length[{p}] > 1
ROOT[os_List, r_List, p_JOINT] := {Line[{os, os + r . p[[1]]}], 
  ROOT[os + r . p[[1]], r . p[[2]], Sequence @@ p[[3 ;;]]]}
ROOT[os_List, r_List, p_END] := Line[{os, os + r . p[[1]]}]

bodyFunction = 
  Function[
   parseBrackets@
      parse@makeSlots@tokenize@bvhHierarchy /. {expr -> Sequence, 
      slot -> Slot} // Evaluate];

Aligning BHV data points with the skeleton
ClearAll[align] (* manually adjusted *)
align[point_] := Threaded[{300, 200, -1100}] + 
    ScalingMatrix[{-10, 10, 10}] . 
     RotationMatrix[90 Degree, {1, 0, 0}] . # &@point

ClearAll[bvhPoints]
bvhPoints[i_] := DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[List @@@ Flatten[
    bodyFunction @@ (ToExpression /@ data[[i]]) /. 
    {offset -> List, c_channel :> channelToRotation[c]} /. 
    {"ROOT" -> ROOT, "JOINT" -> JOINT, "End" -> END} /. 
    {parseBrackets[a : ___] :> a}], 2]

ClearAll[center]
center[1] = Identity;
center[i_] := FindGeometricTransform[{bvhPoints[1][[1]]}, {bvhPoints[i][[1]]} ][[2]]

ClearAll[graphPoints, scaledPoints]
graphPoints[i_] := <|MapIndexed[Rule[#1, First@#2] &]@bvhPoints[i]|>
scaledPoints[i_] := <|MapIndexed[Rule[First@#2, #1] &]@(align@*center[i] /@ bvhPoints[i])|>

ClearAll[graph, f]
graph[i_] := Flatten[f @@@ Flatten[
    bodyFunction @@ (ToExpression /@ data[[i]]) /. 
    {offset -> List, c_channel :> channelToRotation[c]} /. 
    {"ROOT" -> ROOT, "JOINT" -> JOINT, "End" -> END} /. 
    {parseBrackets[a : ___] :> a}], 2] /. 
    f[List[x_, y_]] :> UndirectedEdge[graphPoints[i][x], graphPoints[i][y]] 

Show[Graph3D[graph[1], 
    VertexCoordinates -> (align@*center[1] /@ bvhPoints[1])
     , VertexShapeFunction -> (Sphere[#1, 1] &) 
     , VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeStyle -> Blue]
   , AnatomyPlot3D[ {Opacity[.3], 
     Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SetOfBones"]}]
      , Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> #] & /@ {Front, Left}


Transforming functions
ClearAll[component, transform]
component[from_, to_, iteration_] := component[from, to, iteration] = 
   {{scaledPoints[1][from], scaledPoints[1][to]}
   , {scaledPoints[iteration][from], scaledPoints[iteration][to]}}

transform[{from_, to_}][structure_] := 
 Module[{fromVector, toVector, rotationAxis, rotationAngle, 
   rotationMatrix, translationVector, translated, rotated},
  
  fromVector = Subtract @@ from;
  toVector = Subtract @@ to;
  
  rotationAxis = Cross[fromVector, toVector];
  rotationAngle = VectorAngle[fromVector, toVector];
  rotationMatrix = RotationMatrix[rotationAngle, rotationAxis];
  
  translationVector = First[to] - rotationMatrix . First[from];
  
  rotated = GeometricTransformation[structure, rotationMatrix];
  translated = TransformedRegion[rotated, TranslationTransform[translationVector]]
  ]

Mapping & frames generation
(* long runner ~5' on my machine - 16 Cores *)

frames = ParallelTable[
    Graphics3D[
    {Directive[EdgeForm[]
      , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.35, 0.35, 0.35]}
        , {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}
        , {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}
        , {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}}
      , Specularity[GrayLevel[0.5], 1.5], RGBColor[0.88, 0.847, 0.748]]

     , transform[component[23, 24, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[24, 25, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftTibia"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[24, 25, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFibula"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[25, 27, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkeletonOfLeftFoot"][
       "MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[18, 19, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFemur"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[19, 20, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightTibia"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[19, 20, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFibula"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[20, 22, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkeletonOfRightFoot"][
       "MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[14, 15, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHumerus"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[15, 16, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftRadius"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[15, 16, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftUlna"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[16, 17, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkeletonOfLeftHand"][
       "MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[9, 10, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightHumerus"]["MeshRegion"] ] 
     , transform[component[10, 11, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightRadius"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[10, 11, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightUlna"]["MeshRegion"]]
     , transform[component[11, 12, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SkeletonOfRightHand"][
       "MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[18, 23, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "HipBone"] ["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[18, 23, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Sacrum"] ["MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[3, 5, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Vertebra"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[13, 14, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftScapula"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     , transform[component[8, 9, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightScapula"]["MeshRegion"] ] 
     , transform[component[13, 14, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftClavicle"]["MeshRegion"] ] 
     , transform[component[8, 9, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightClavicle"]["MeshRegion"] ] 
     
     , transform[component[3, 5, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RibCage"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     
     , transform[component[6, 7, n]][
      Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Skull"]["MeshRegion"]] 
     
     }
    , SphericalRegion -> True
    , Boxed -> False
    , ViewPoint -> {0.99, -1.61, -0.02}]
   , {n, 2, Length@data -1, 1}];

Export["walking.gif", frames, "GIF"]

Original Post:
An attempt, perhaps as a starting point for something more sophisticated.
rightFoot = 
  Intersection[ 
   EntityList @EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure", "Bones"] , 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFoot"]["ConstitutionalParts"]];
leftFoot = 
  Intersection[ 
   EntityList @EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure", "Bones"] , 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFoot"] ["ConstitutionalParts"]];
rightHand = 
  Intersection[ 
   EntityList @EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure", "Bones"] , 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightHand"]["ConstitutionalParts"]];
leftHand = 
  Intersection[ 
   EntityList @EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure", "Bones"] , 
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHand"]["ConstitutionalParts"]];
{x, y, z } = {0, -96, 845};

Manipulate[
 AnatomyPlot3D[
  {Select[EntityList@EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure", "Bones"] 
    , FreeQ[{
       Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftTibia"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFibula"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftPatella"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFemur"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightTibia"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFibula"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightPatella"]
       , Splice@rightFoot
       , Splice@leftFoot
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHumerus"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftUlna"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftRadius"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightHumerus"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightUlna"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightRadius"]
       , Splice@rightHand
       , Splice@leftHand
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Coccyx"]}, #] &]
    , Rotate[{
         Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightHumerus"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightUlna"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightRadius"]
       , Splice@rightHand}
      , Dynamic[20*Sin[\[Pi]*(t/40 + 0.5)] Degree], {1, 0, 0}, {x, y, z + 455}]
    , Rotate[{
         Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftHumerus"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftUlna"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftRadius"]
       , Splice@leftHand}
      , Dynamic[-20*Sin[\[Pi]*(t/40 + 0.5)] Degree], {1, 0, 0}, {x, y, z + 455}]
   , Rotate[{
         Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFemur"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightTibia"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightFibula"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "RightPatella"]
       , Splice@rightFoot}
      , Dynamic[-20*Sin[\[Pi]*(t/40 + 0.5)] Degree], {1, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}]
   , Rotate[{
         Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftTibia"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFibula"]
       , Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftPatella"]
       , Splice@leftFoot}
      , Dynamic[20*Sin[\[Pi]*(t/40 + 0.5)] Degree], {1, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}]
   }
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  , ViewPoint -> {0.99, -1.61, -0.02}
  , PlotRangePadding -> 20], {t, -40, 40, 2}
 , SynchronousUpdating -> False]



Nice (+1). It will be better if his/her knees bend :-)

@A.Kato Thank you for the upvote! Yes, bending the knees would definitely make it more realistic...

(+1) very very nice, thank you. Though I agree with @A.Kato about bending knees :-) still I would like to note that the original question goes a bit beyond. It is about attaching a realistic model of walking from models or data. For example the one demo I linked in question or maybe from data ( see on comment on my question about BV ).

@VitaliyKaurov Thank you for the upvote! Of course, I'm fully aware that there's still a long way to go to meet the question's main requirements; nevertheless, I decided to post it, as it might help with further developments.

@VitaliyKaurov Of course, I've sent you my contact details.
